# How to get full URL to display in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http, url, request

I'm a beginner at laravel, I wanna display the live URL of the current page on a page.

> // Full URL, with query string $request->fullUrl()
>
> // Just the path part of the URL  $request->path()
>
> // Just the root (protocol and domain) part of the URL)
>   $request->r*emphasized text*oot()

After searching on google I've found this, can anyone please tell me if this is right way and if it is how to implement this. like what to write in "***Routes***" and what to write in "***controller***".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/urls):

```
// Get the current URL without the query string...
echo url()->current();

// Get the current URL including the query string...
echo url()->full();
```

Each of these methods may also be accessed via the URL facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

echo URL::current();
```

If you're using [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#named-routes) (not mandatory):

```
echo route('post.show', ['post' => 1]);

// http://example.com/post/1
```

Comment: yes but i need to display it to the user... how do i call it in the view (sorry if it sounds dumb)

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. You can use URL::full()

In the view you can use {{ URL::full() }} to display the full url to the users

Answer (score -1):

**To Get Full, Current & Previous URL**

```
// Get the current URL without the query string...
echo url()->current();


// Get the current URL including the query string...
echo url()->full();


// Get the full URL for the previous request...
echo url()->previous();
```

**To Get Specific Segment Of Url**

```
{{ Request::segment(1) }}
```